# SQL Update with count for each row

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sql-update

I'm trying to update a field of a table with the count of occurrences from another table but am having no luck so far. This is what I have:

```
Update S
SET Hours = Hours + COUNT(S.ID)
FROM S, E
ON S.ID = E.ID
WHERE S.ID = E.ID
GROUP BY S.ID;
```

The program I'm being forced to use has terrible error handling and can only provide me with the description of the error being a syntax error. I've already successfully implemented a select statement that returns what I want:

```
Select COUNT(S.ID) 
FROM S, E
WHERE S.ID = E.ID
GROUP BY S.ID;
```

Am I missing something very simple here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update s
   set hours =
       (select count(*) from e where e.id = s.id)
```

Comment: You are missing a part of the update.. The op wants to add the count with his hours column not just replace with the number of occurrences in case you want to fix it :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell The select query that he provided, which he claims provides the resulting counts that he wants, does not do that. The "hours + count" is within his "bad query" which he says doesn't work. Elsewhere he says he wants to update it with just the count.

Comment: I must've misread that because I was thinking that when the op says that query returns what he wants it was the numbers he wants to add to his column... But it could also mean replace so I dono now.

Comment: I was able to modify this to be hours = hours + (select count(*) .....) to work for my program.  For some reason, the other solutions below were not allowed by the compiler (likely due to bad parsing - I will be glad when I am done using it as a tool).

Answer (score 1):

```
Update S
JOIN
(
  select id, COUNT(*) as cnt
  from e
  group by id
) TMP ON S.ID = TMP.ID
SET S.Hours = S.Hours + TMP.cnt
```